# R crashes while using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

sac[,treatment_days := as.character(seq(from = SACDPDAT, to = SACRTDAT, by = "1 day")), by = PACKID] I have data named sac with dput(sac[1:2,]) as follows:

```
structure(list(SUBJECT_Blinded = c(1201001, 1101001), LINE = c(8, 
4), MODULE = c("SAC", "SAC"), CENTRE_Blinded = c(1201, 1201), 
STUDYPER = c(7, 4), PACKID = c(10096, 10595), SACDPDAT = structure(c(1335304800, 
1325545200), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = ""), 
SACDP1 = c(35, 35), C_SACDP = c(NA_character_, NA_character_
), SACRTDAT = structure(c(1340316000, 1327964400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = ""), SACRT1 = c(0, 9), C_SACRT = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_)), .Names = c("SUBJECT_Blinded", "LINE", "MODULE", 
"CENTRE_Blinded", "STUDYPER", "PACKID", "SACDPDAT", "SACDP1", 
"C_SACDP", "SACRTDAT", "SACRT1", "C_SACRT"), sorted = c("SUBJECT_Blinded", 
"PACKID"), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

When I running the code:

```
sac[,treatment_days := list(format(seq(from = SACDPDAT, to = SACRTDAT, by = "1 day"),"%Y-%m-%d")), by = PACKID]
```

RStudio crushes and returns info:

```
Problem signature:
Problem Event Name: APPCRASH
Application Name:   rsession.exe
Application Version:    0.98.501.0
Application Timestamp:  52e8371d
Fault Module Name:  R.dll
Fault Module Version:   3.3.65126.0
Fault Module Timestamp: 53185fd3
Exception Code: c0000005
Exception Offset:   0000000000028c36
OS Version: 6.1.7601.2.1.0.256.48
Locale ID:  1045
Additional Information 1:   4fc0
Additional Information 2:   4fc0e6e5b53a870c89fb6e37a38d7e6b
Additional Information 3:   9d6e
Additional Information 4:   9d6e8f79167930945e5a5d06afac680e
```

It's the same with pure R. Any ideas how to do it another way?

Comment: fyi, you cant actually use the output from `dput` on a `data.table`, due to `data.table`'s use of pointers.

Comment: @ScottRitchie fixed that for you

Comment: What do you expect your new table to look like?

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of problems with your new code:

1. `"1 day"` is incorrect, if you run `seq` on a date object, the number you pass to `by` will be interpreted as days, so:

   ```
   seq(from = SACDPDAT, to = SACRTDAT, by = 1)
   ```
2. You also cannot create a new column from this sequence, because there can only be one value for each row. Instead, you can generate the sequence of days by `PACKID`, and then `join` this onto the old `data.table`

So try:

```
setkey(sac, PACKID)
sac <- sac[sac[,seq(from = SACDPDAT, to = SACRTDAT, by = 1), by=PACKID]]
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, sorry, I've put there wrong code, now there is a line which I had in mind.